# Unable to click on "know more..." link on the page given below using the selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, frame

page url: https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiVBL.png)

I tried using switch to frames from selenium webdriver, still it doesn't help me

Below is the code sample

```java
WebElement frame = DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='login_page']"));
DriverManager.getDriver().switchTo().frame(frame);
DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='nortonimg2']/div/span/following-sibling::span/a")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to switch to the frame and then click the proper element inside it.
The following code should work:

```java
WebElement frame = DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='login_page']"));
DriverManager.getDriver().switchTo().frame(frame);
DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='welcomesec2']//a")).click();
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there but the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) for the link ***Know More...*** was slightly off as there are multiple elements with almost similar attributes:

[image: 2elements]

---

### Solution

You can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *partialLinkText*:

  ```
  WebElement frame = DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("frame[name='login_page']"));
  DriverManager.getDriver().switchTo().frame(frame);
  DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.partialLinkText("More...")).click();
  ```
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement frame = DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("frame[name='login_page']"));
  DriverManager.getDriver().switchTo().frame(frame);
  DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("div#welcomesec1 span.lightbluecolor > a")).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement frame = DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='login_page']"));
  DriverManager.getDriver().switchTo().frame(frame);
  DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='welcomesec1']//span[starts-with(., 'Your security is of utmost')]//following::span/a[starts-with(., 'Know') and contains(., 'More...')]")).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Although your XPath for 'Know More' link is correct, somehow web driver is not able to click on it. Try a different XPath for the same 'Know More' link, like below:

```
WebElement frame = DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='login_page']"));
DriverManager.getDriver().switchTo().frame(frame);
DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nortonimg1\"]/div[2]/span[2]/a")).click();
```